# Python Runserver error based on Mac vs Windows Environment

Tags: python, django, pandas, numpy

[Nonexistant Parent Node Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Fu0h.png)

the repository for this is. I'm using windows so I installed everything and I get this error, is there someway I could fix this problem on Windows, apparently it works fine on MAC, I used miniconda to install numpy and panda. Django and python 3.5 are also installed with system environment variable paths. Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

New Error,Updated

Final Edit: Solved the problem thank you.

Comment: just delete `patterns` in first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - Have you tried install with virtual env?
2 - Which version of the Django are you using? You should use the 1.7...
3 - As the last resort I'd remove the patterns from the tournament/urls.py

Original:
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
NEW:
from django.conf.urls import include, url

I really think it is the django version the problem...